# zsh: command not found: brew while it exists

Tags: macos, path, homebrew

I remember that I used brew some time ago. But now when I try to run it I get

```
➜  ~ brew      
zsh: command not found: brew
```

but there is an alias `/usr/local/bin/brew`  which I can run.
Also it's location is in my `PATH` variable:

```
➜  ~ echo $PATH
/Users/kosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/bin:/Users/kosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2@global/bin:/Users/kosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.2/bin:/usr/local/opt/gradle@6/bin:”/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/kosh/Documents/Development/flutter/bin:/Users/kosh/.rvm/bin://Users/kosh/Library/Android/sdk/tools://Users/kosh/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin://Users/kosh/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools”
```

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

As a shell I use Oh My Zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothesis: somewhere in your startup scripts there is something like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/opt/gradle@6/bin:”$PATH”
```

which should be like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/opt/gradle@6/bin:"$PATH"
```

At this point your `$PATH` expanded to `/usr/local/bin:…`. Because [curly quotes are not special to the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704763/108618), they are not removed during quote removal phase. In effect they literally appeared in your new `$PATH`.

In the `$PATH` you posted, the entry most similar to `/usr/local/bin` is `”/usr/local/bin` which is *not* `/usr/local/bin`. Similarly `//Users/kosh/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools”` is not `//Users/kosh/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`.

Some websites change regular quotes to curly quotes, because apparently their purpose it to hold literature or any non-technical text (where curly quotes look nice), not code. IMO such behavior is an indication the site is not a good source of any code. Maybe you have copied from such site.

Or maybe you have edited one of your startup scripts in a text editor that "knows better" and changes regular quotes to curly quotes.

You should review every script that adds to your `$PATH`, find these curly quotes and fix them (change to regular double-quotes). And never use curly quotes in shell scripting.